# Execute function from properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a menu "dynamicaly" in Javascript. But I want to add some onClick handlers when needed. For example to open a second menu...

This is what I am doing:

I have the items declared like this:

```
export const mobileMenuItems = [
    {
        "identifier": "View all categories",
        "url": "/all-categories",
        "urlText": "View all categories",
        "cssClass": "headerLinkArrow",
        'clickHandler': 'openAllCategoriesHandler'
    },
    ...desktopMenuItems,

]
```

And then I create the links like this:

```
mobileMenuItems.map(mobileMenuItem => {

    return (
        <Menu.Item as={"div"}
                   key={'mobileMenuItem' + mobileMenuItem.identifier}
                   className={'p-2'}>
            {({active}) => (

                <Link href={mobileMenuItem.url}>
                    <a onClick={mobileMenuItem.clickHandler}
                       className={_.join([active, mobileMenuItem.cssClass], ' ')}>
                        {mobileMenuItem.urlText}
                    </a>
                </Link>
            )}
        </Menu.Item>
    )
})
```

and then I am defining the handler in the same file where I am generating the menu:

```
const openAllCategoriesHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

The question is how can I make the handler execute? Or is this even possible in Javascript?

Comment: Did you try to write `'clickHandler': openAllCategoriesHandler`, then the object property will use the actual handler, and not a string value?

Comment: `'clickHandler': 'openAllCategoriesHandler'` why not pass the actual variable here? Or even an arrow function. You are only passing a string value here.

Comment: pass the actual function and not string name in  `'clickHandler': 'openAllCategoriesHandler'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi remove anchor tag or link tag first. Then create a single handler for all menus and handle according to value passed in handler. Also redirect in handler function

```js
mobileMenuItems.map(mobileMenuItem => {

    return (
        <Menu.Item as={"div"}
                   key={'mobileMenuItem' + mobileMenuItem.identifier}
                   className={'p-2'}>
            {({active}) => (

                <Link href={mobileMenuItem.url} onClick={() => {
//clickHandler("type")
}}>
   <p className={_.join([active, mobileMenuItem.cssClass], ' ')}>
      {mobileMenuItem.urlText}
   </p>
</Link>
            )}
        </Menu.Item>
    )
})
```